# Maven POM error - POM is missing

Tags: maven

I am trying to build a maven project. My other team members are able to build it without issues. I get the following errors:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.hectorclient:hector-core:jar:1.0-3 is missing, no dependency information 
available
[WARNING] The POM for org.hectorclient:hector-test:jar:1.0-3 is missing, no dependency information     
available
```

Then the build fails with the error: Could not resolve dependencies for the project XYZ. What could be possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Surely the `jar` is missing from your `.m2` local repository.
Assuming the dependency is written in the pom.

What I suggest:

1. Case: When you have internet

   1. fire `mvn install` that will follow your `POM.xml` and it will download all the necessary jars.
   2. then fire `mvn compile` to build.
2. Case: You are having restricted internet connection that is restricting / no Internet

   1. Take the repository + POM from other machine that is compiling successfully
   2. then fire `mvn  -o compile`

I assume it will solve your case.

Comment: The problem is that it downloads the jar but not the POM for that library. How do I resolve this?

Comment: If still unresolved , Can you share the part of the pom ?

Answer (score 3):

@Vaibs You are correct. Adding to your answer:

"Check the settings.xml of yours and the others. If you are not able to download the dependencies from internet like the one you mentioned due to some reason then  you will need to set up maven somewhere else and and fire "mvn install" there to get the latest dependencies and put those .m2 into yours."

Comment: Where can I find settings.xml ? I don't see it in Maven project I created