# dist and native-win could not be activated, no POM in directory

Tags: maven

[image: error screenshot]

Please explain what is required to be done stepwise.
How to activate -dist and native-win?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven POM error - POM is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886024/maven-pom-error-pom-is-missing)

Answer (score 0):

I saw your error contains `there is no pom in this directory`.
Maven can run only from the location where pom file exists so make sure pom file is there in your project.
For example, your project is inside C:\Users\HP then so maven will consider HP as a project and it will try to find pom file inside HP project.

Comment: ok.. i got your point and made some changes.now i am shown the message that build is succeessful, along with 2 warnings: requested profile "dist " and "native-win" could not be activated because it does not exist .any idea abt this ?

Comment: Yes, you have to set profiles "dist" and "native-win" in your project. You should invoke mvn like this: mvn package -DenvConfig=dist,native-win -DskipTests

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because you didnot place hadoop source package in the C:/User/HP directory. you can download appropriate source package from http://www.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/

unzip it and place all the files & folder in C:/User/HP then run your maven package command. It should work